# Resizing images and image formats

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, format

Below is my php code that I use to retrieve 3 images of type blob in mysql database!

Though I was successfull in retrieving them, I do not understand how to embed the html code in order to control the height and width of the retrieved images!

Also here I am able to retrieve images of type png.

Please help me to retrieve images in any fomat (eg jpeg) based on the format of the image I upload to the database (I've already obtained the types of the uploaded image.(eg-`$images1=getimagesize($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']);
$imagetype1=$images1['mime'];)`.

SO I need 2 main helps:

1. To adjust the width and height of the images retrieved from the above php code
2. To retrieve images in format

   ```
   <?php
           require("includes/db.php");

           $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
           $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

   echo "<table>";


   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {

   echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["OrderNo."];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["NIC"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["DP"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["Address"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["DPTime"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["Telephone"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row["Email"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
   echo"<td >";
   echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image1'] ).' " />';

   echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
   echo"<td >";
   echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image2'] ).' "/>';

   echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
     echo"<td >";
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image3'] ).' "/>';

   echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";

    echo"</tr>";

   }
   echo "</table>";

   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

// This is the temporary file created by PHP
$uploadedfile ="search.png";

// Create an Image from it so we can do the resize
 $info = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
//$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);


list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

$newwidth=80;
$newheight=($height/$width)*80;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);


$filename =$uploadedfile;
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);











?>
```

This make resize images.